# get property from id class

Tags: objective-c, class, properties

```
ABC *abc=[ABC new];
id property=abc.property;
```

but:

```
id ClassName=NSClassFromString(ABC);
id instance=[ClassName new];

id property=???????;
```

i can't use instance.property,because it is id type.

i want to get a known property from (id)type class.

i try to use:

```
[aInstanse propertyForKey:<#(NSString *)#>];
[aInstanse propertyNamed:<#(NSString *)#>];
```

But Program crashes...

can you help me, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there are many ways

you can cast it if you know the type at compile time

```
id property=((MyClass *)instance).myProperty;
((MyClass *)instance).myProperty = property;
```

or not using dot syntax

```
id property=[instance myProperty];
[instance setMyProperty:property];
```

or using `valueForKey:`

```
id property=[instance valueForKey:@"myProperty"];
[instance setValue:property forKey:@"myProperty"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the standard getters and setters, which default properties have and which `@synthesize` will create:

```
[instance property];
[instance setProperty:value];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that your class has some properties, and you know name of this properties, you can make an interface to call it.
Of course, you have to cast your object to an object of this class!

Good luck!