# Getting class instance properties assigning it through id variable

Tags: objective-c

I'm in the process of studying Objective-C. If I understand correctly, using code like this:

```
id data;
myClass = [[NSObject alloc]init];
data = myClass;
```

Assigning `myClass` instance to `data`, therefore, I can use `data` just like I could use `myClass`.

The following code is working correctly:

```
data = myClass;
[data methodBelongToMyClass];
```

But I can't get access to properties of the class. Please take a look (numerator is property of myClass):

```
myClass.numerator = numerator * dataValue.denominator;
```

It crashes (actually not even running) because of an error - `Property denominator not found on object of type '__strond id'`

Yes, I understand its kind of self-explanatory, but, I already assigned class instance to my id object, so why can't I get access to properties?

Any help and explanation would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused by your question but I will try to answers it.

Because id is considered an "any" it doesn't know about properties unless you cast it to the object type you set it equal to. However you can do this.

```
[data valueForKey@"propertyName"]
```

Using id can be very powerful but can also be abused and give you a lot of headache when trying to debug.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah . but i suggest compiler understand and assign all of values and properties to new id object.

Comment: Sadly that isn't how id works. Id is meant to be an 'any' object and doesn't know about properties and methods of what it inherits from. In most cases you wouldn't use id as your are in your example. In my experience I don't see id used a ton by developers. Things like NSArray and NSDictionary take and id but you always cast it as something when you take it out. For example MyClass *myClass = myArray[0]; That way the compiler knows what you are trying to do. I hope that helps a little bit.

Comment: Thanks its helpful, but your code produce an error - Invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'id') - [dataValue valueForKey:@"numerator"]; How else could i retrieve that value? In fact i just want to know "how the things work", and that is not about practical usage :)

Comment: You will want to cast it as the data type it is intended to be (int)[data valueForKey@"denominator"] from the sounds of it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `data` is an `id` type not `NSObject`.
The compiler doesn't know what type of data is in `id data` so it can't refer to it.

If you create a casting i.e

```
id data = MyCalss;
NSObject *object = (NSObject *)data;
```

you could access the internal data in the class.

Comment: But why compiler know about methods? Variables are also declared in .h file, just like class instance methods.

Comment: I could be mistaken but I don't think the compiler knows about that method on that id. It knows there is a method out there called that likely because of an import. id allows you to pass "messages" to it in hopes that it responds accordingly however this is some of the challenges with using id your app can crash if that method isn't actually on that id and the compiler knowns none the wiser.

Comment: id is a way for you to pass data around as a "generic" data type. you can point to any type of data with id. But id doesn't know about any existing methods of existing classes.

Comment: Maybe compiler don't know about methods, but it autofill its name and not produce errors, i guess it look for method description at runtime. But why not with properties? They are the same methods, setters and getters..

Comment: Actually you may be able to do [myClass denominator] because it is the same calling the getter. You might want to also look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661342/get-property-from-id-class

Comment: @SkylerLauren i found at interesting thing, i can actually get values to class properties by setter/getter method but NOT through dot syntax.. Is that bug or Obj-C feature?  f.numerator produce an error, but [f numerator]; doesn't.

Comment: Yup that is what I was trying to point out in the above comment. It is a feature of id and Objective-C. Glad your question is solved.