# Is it possible to change dynamically the name of the class in the code with a variable?

Tags: ios, class, variables, instance

I have this function :

```
- (NSString*) getId:(id)id_field withColumn:(int)test_column withTable:(NSString *) tableName  //renvoyer le label
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:tableName
                                              inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (<tableName of class> *info in fetchedObjects)
    {
        if (test_column == LBL2_CLMN)
        {
            NSLog(@"info.id :%@", info.id);
            if ([info.id compare:id_field] == NSOrderedSame)
                NSLog(@"info.id :%@", info.label1);
            return info.label1;
        }
        else if (test_column == LBL1_CLMN)
        {
            if ([info.id compare:id_field] == NSOrderedSame)
                return info.label2;
        }
    }
    return @"";
}
```

How can I change the name of the class  for instanciate *info with the variable tableName ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the NSClassFromString method and then use id keyword to get the object:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:table inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

Class theClass = NSClassFromString(table);
id info = [theClass new];

for (info in fetchedObjects)
{
   .....
}

return @"";
```

Comment: Wow, you're a god.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, but since `executeFetchRequest` returns `NSManagedObject` use that in the repeat loop and cast the object to the expected class in the `if - else` scopes.

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *object in fetchedObjects)
{
    if (test_column == LBL2_CLMN)
    {
        ClassA *info = (ClassA *)object;
        NSLog(@"info.id :%@", info.id);
        if ([info.id compare:id_field] == NSOrderedSame) {
            NSLog(@"info.id :%@", info.label1);
            return info.label1;
        }
    }
    else if (test_column == LBL1_CLMN)
    {
        ClassB *info = (ClassB *)object;         
        if ([info.id compare:id_field] == NSOrderedSame)
            return info.label2;
    }
}
return @"";
```

And I guess that there is a pair of braces missing in the second `if` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much, you hit the target :D

Comment: A little thing. I don't know how to instiate with that : ClassA *info = (ClassA *)object; and using the tableName variable...?

Comment: Creating (evaluating) dynamic variable or class names at runtime is not possible. But you can do `if ([tableName isEqualToString:@"table1"])` and cast the object respectively.

Comment: The problem is that I have 100 tables like that. Is there another way than doing : if ([tableName isEqualToString:@"table1"])
            talbe1 *table ...
if ([tableName isEqualToString:@"table2"])
            talbe2 *table ...
....

Comment: Instead of `info.id` you could use the more generic `[info valueForKey:@"id"]` on `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: Yep it works but the problem is that when I want to return the value [info valueForKey:@"label1"] based on the same principle, I have a message error : **CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Table_civility' **

Comment: At some point you have to cast the type for example `[(Table_civility *)info valueForKey:@"label1"]`

Comment: That's the point. Is there a solution not to use (Table_civility *) but instead a variable. I am trying with that but I don't know if it is possible :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661342/get-property-from-id-class

Comment: As mentioned before, dynamic typing at runtime is not possible because the types must be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: But why NSClassFromString() is it for ?

Comment: `NSClassFromString()` is for to get a static type from a dynamic argument. But the compiler needs static types anyway while evaluating the terminology of that type at **compile** time.

Comment: Oh ok. It is a pity, so I will copy 100 times. Thank you for your advices :)