# Is it possible to instantiate a class with a string?

Tags: objective-c, class, instance

I have 50 classes with names like : table_address, table_name, table_lastname, etc...

Instead of doing :

```
table_address *table;
table =[[table alloc] init];
id_to_send = table.id;

table_name *table;
table =[[table alloc] init];
id_to_send = table.id;

table_lastname *table;
table =[[table alloc] init];
id_to_send = table.id;
```

etc...

Is there a way to have only one loop that can declare the tables and instantiate them to extract the id from every table. I hope I am not forced to write that 100 times...

For example :

```
for (first table to last table)
{
    table_xxxxxxx *table;
    table =[[table alloc] init];
    id_to_send = table.id;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do `[[NSClassFromString(@"...") alloc] init]`

Comment: @Claudio you can use pattern [Table Module](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html). So, each field from table will be an instance of class. ( table ). So, all columns will be encapsulated into one entity.

Comment: Oh really? I am going to explore that solution.

Comment: @Claudio, sorry, not correct. each row of table will be an instance of class ( table ).
You will have, for example, UserInformationTableClass and each row of that table ( UserInformationTable ) will be an instance of class ( UserInformationTableClass ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:
There is finally a solution.
I found the solution. You can find it here :D**

=> [Is it possible to change dynamically the name of the class in the code with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579112/is-it-possible-to-change-dynamically-the-name-of-the-class-in-the-code-with-a-va/45354177#45354177)

Comment: again, you can use code generators like JSONAccelerator.

Comment: So, I will explore that solution too. Thank you for it. I will post here if it works.

Comment: I don't understand what JSON will have to do with an dynamical instanciation ?

Comment: well, it is an alternative solution. you can create code generated classes from JSON ( for example, you have samples from needed API collection ) or you can use ( as you want ) dynamic classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSClassFromString to create the class dynamically. It creates a Class Reference corresponding to the name you provide

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString

Assuming they all inherit from a class that contains the property id you could do something like the following

```
NSArray * classSuffixes = @[@"suffix1", @"suffix2", @"suffix100"];
for(NSString * suffix in classSuffixes) {
    NSString *tableIdentifier;

    NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"table_%@",suffix];
    Class objectClass = NSClassFromString(className);
    CommonParentClass *table = (CommonParentClass *)[[objectClass alloc] init];
    tableIdentifier = table.id;
    // ....
}
```

For an NSManagedObject you could do the following:

```
    NSArray * classSuffixes = @[@"suffix1", @"suffix2", @"suffix100"];
    for(NSString * suffix in classSuffixes) {
        NSString *tableIdentifier;

        NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"table_%@",suffix];
        Class objectClass = NSClassFromString(className);
        NSManagedObject *table = [[objectClass alloc] init];
        NSArray *availableKeys = [[table.entity attributesByName] allKeys];
        if ([availableKeys containsObject:@"id"]) {
            tableIdentifier = [table valueForKey:@"id"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, my problem comes with that part :     CommonParentClass *table = (CommonParentClass *)[[objectClass alloc] init];
    tableIdentifier = table.id;   It doesn't recognize CommonParentClass. How Can I instantiate when I did Class objectClass ?

Comment: I assumed all your classes inherit from a common class to be able to cast the received object. In your example  where you have table_address, table_name, they would all inherit from a common class that could be table_field. In that case table_field would be our CommonParentClass and would be the one declaring the property "id"

Comment: mmmm I see. To resume, I have Table_civility, Table_contact, Table_YesNo etc... that have been created by CoreData. So that's why this is not inherit from a common class. I know that dynamic typing at runtime is not possible because the types must be evaluated at compile time, but I believed I could do a "trick" :D

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution that should work for NSManagedObjects without any trick

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that my problem can not be resolved as dynamic typing at runtime is not possible because the types must be evaluated at compile time. That's the main problem